# Problem on deploying Docker image on Heroku (react app)

Tags: node.js, docker, heroku, create-react-app

I have an App which have separate backend and frontend in two different folders. (Nodejs and React)
I am running them both on Docker and locally everything is fine. Now I am trying to deploy them on Heroku. So far, they are deployed, and I don't have any problem with backend but for my frontend when I check the Heroku logs, I get these:

```
2020-07-17T00:41:07.783090+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=serene-tundra-72728.herokuapp.com fwd="96.20.56.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2020-07-17T00:41:08.398622+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=serene-tundra-72728.herokuapp.com
```

also:

```
2020-07-17T01:58:24.005508+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /ISS-CLIENT/public
2020-07-17T01:58:24.005601+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
```

I am not sure if there is only one issue here or more. I have read a lot of articles but none was clear enough.

This is my first post here and I'm new to coding, so I will appreciate any help.

**PS:**      My frontend [repo](https://github.com/Ashkanrpd/ISS-Weather-Client).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after reading a lot of articles i was able to fix this by:

- Downgrading the "react-scripts" from  "3.4.1" to "3.4.0".
- Also i have removed every unnecessary files from create-react-app installation.

I hope this information will be helpful.